# Folder Restructure and Merge Conflict in SVN

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

One of our project folders get conflicted during SVN merge after a folder restructure. I am not sure if there is a way to resolve the conflict during the merge. The conflict also causes it not to find the differences between the files from the old folder structure. Below is a simplistic scenario of the situation.

- /folder/path1/file.txt @rev1  //Here we have the original file at the original path
- /folder/path2/file.txt @rev2  //The file get updated with new content and then moved to a new to folder path. This is where the conflict happens. During SVN merge, SVN tend to see the file.txt in the new path as a new object

Is this what SVN move is intended to solve? Or has this been the weak point of SVN when it comes to merging and folder restructure?

Comment: If all else fail start from fresh checkout and make changes there.

Comment: Yes, this is what svn move is intended to solve. Is it safe to assume you did not use an SVN command to rename the file?

Comment: The file was not renamed rather it was deleted from path1 and then added to path2. When I look at SVN Move command I am not sure if it is supposed to help with preserving the merge info on file.txt on path2 from path1 that way any differences found it can merge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one of the weak point of SVN. We had to use SVN Move for future references so that when SVN does the branch it will know which file to track.